# CSS. Ghost style of button in mobile device

Tags: html, css

Below 2 versions of the same page. There is a submit button, which has an orange style and it appears correctly in desktop. On the second screen button has gradient and completely different style. This magic appears only on mobile devices. I look through whole css and didn't find any kind of style. Chrome mobile emulator displays it correctly. So my question: how to debug and fix this style?
Some thech details: magnific popup plugi for modal, the style of button:

```
.form .btn, .beeline-custom .form input.btn {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 239px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 16.5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fec81e !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    color: #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font: 17px/1.2 'Roboto-Regular',sans-serif;
}
```

[image]

[image]

**UPD** Problem fixed by BenM's comment: -webkit-appearance: none to button css

Comment: I would recommend you to check your style for browser compatibility because some browsers have different tags

Comment: Try using `-webkit-appearance: none` on the button (along with other browser prefixes as required).

Comment: @BenM thanks a lot dude, that works!

Comment: @EugeneMescheryakov No problem, have added it as an answer for you.

Comment: Little headsup: you have quite some double declarations in your css. (ie `background` & `padding`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override any browser defaults by using the [`appearance`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/) CSS property. Set it to `none` and you should be good to go:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
```